# How to redirect with POST method inside jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I hava  a form element with some contents inside as given below.

```
<form action="insertserverdata.php" id="toPopup">
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td>IP address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ip" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input id="btnLogin" type="submit"/>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the following jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#btnLogin').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var posting = $.post( "connectServer.php", { ip: $('#ip').val() } );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        if($.trim(data)=="1"){
                      //need to reedirect to connectServer.php
        }else{
        alert(data);
    }       
});

});
</script>
```

Here everything works fine, and I got `1` in variable named `data` inside jquery. Here the problem is, if the value of variable `data` is `1` then I need to redirect to ConnectServer.php.What shall I need to do for that purpose ?

Thanks in advance dear friends. Please advice.

Comment: You have syntax error in your code, you missed one `});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ways to redirect URL in javascript

```
window.location.href = 'connectServer.php';
```

OR

```
document.location = 'connectServer.php';
```

Refer this link http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.trim(data)=="1"){
  window.location = 'connectServer.php';
}
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Answer (score 0):

You can use either window.location or document.location to redirect to a specific page.

```
document.location = "connectServer.php";
```